# Displaying images when replying with Outlook template

Tags: vba, outlook

I have an Outlook template which I use when I reply to a message. I can get it to successfully show by itself but when I add the original message to display under the template the images become corrupt.

[image]
[image]

In the second image the original message is fine and even displays the images correctly.

```
Sub Reply()

Dim Original As Outlook.MailItem
Dim Reply As Outlook.MailItem
Set Original = Application.ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).Reply
Set Reply = Application.CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Mail.oft")

Original.HTMLBody = Reply.HTMLBody & Original.HTMLBody
Original.Display
End Sub
```

Comment: Can you debug.print the HTMLBodies as a first check?

Comment: "debug.print Original.HTMLBody" before you display.

Answer (score 0):

Try working with Reply not Original. Someone else would have to provide an explanation.

```
Sub Reply()

Dim Original As mailItem
Dim Reply As mailItem

Set Original = ActiveExplorer.Selection(1).Reply
Set Reply = CreateItemFromTemplate("C:\Mail.oft")

Reply.HTMLBody = Reply.HTMLBody & Original.HTMLBody
Reply.Display

End Sub
```